# How to run a nested logit model with fixed effects in R or Stata?

Tags: logistic, panel-data, fixed-effects-model

I would like to run a nested logit model with panel data in R or Stata, but I am not sure how to proceed. I want to understand which factors influenced a person's choice to work full time, work part time, or not work at all.

I have the following panel dataset:

- 1,500 person-year observations -- There are 50 people in my dataset. I observe each person's choice to work every year for 30 years, so I have 30 observations per person. Each line in my data is one person-year.
- Categorical measure of whether a person worked full time, worked part time, or did not work in a given year
- Set of individual level, time varying factors that could affect work choice (e.g., number of kids under 18, whether the person is enrolled in university, etc)

I would like to run a nested logistic model where my DV is a dichotomous nested variable with two levels. The first level is work or not work, and the second level is full time or part time. [image]

I have seen a few R packages (e.g., `nestedLogit`, `mlogit`) and a Stata command (`nlogit`) that are designed to handle models like this. However, because this is panel data, I would also like to include individual fixed effects. I know that fixed effects do weird things in non-linear models, but there do exist commands that address these issues and allow the inclusion of fixed effects in logit models (e.g., `feglm` from the `fixest` library in R, `femlogit` in Stata). I do not want random effects.

**My question is this**: Can I add individual fixed effects to a nested logit model in R or Stata? If so, how? Can I do this with any of the existing nested logit commands (e.g., `nestedLogit`, `mlogit`, `nlogit`)?